# Loop through all elements of a barplot container

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to loop through all elements in a container but end up missing some. The code am using is below. One will notice the label for endline has no N

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

data = {
'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22],
'survey': ['baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline'],
'level': ['low', 'high', 'medium', 'low', 'high', 'medium', 'medium', 'high', 'low', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'low', 'medium', 'low', 'high', 'low', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'high', 'high', 'high', 'medium', 'low', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'medium', 'low', 'high', 'high', 'medium', 'medium', 'low', 'high', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

N = df.groupby(['survey', 'level']).count().sort_index(ascending = True).reset_index()
N['%'] = 100 * N['id'] / N.groupby('survey')['id'].transform('sum')

sns.set_style('white')
ax = sns.barplot(data = N, x = 'survey', y = '%', ci = None,
                palette="rainbow", hue = 'level')

labels = [
    [f'{pct:.1f}% $(N={_n})$' for pct, _n in zip(c.datavalues, n)]
    for c, n in zip(ax.containers, pd.DataFrame(N['id']).to_numpy())
]

for container, label in zip(ax.containers, labels):
    ax.bar_label(container, label, fontsize = 10)

sns.despine(ax = ax, left = True)
ax.grid(True, axis = 'y')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(100))
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_ylabel('')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1.02, 1), loc = 'upper left', borderaxespad=0)
plt.show()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn creates one bar container for each of the hue values.  To provide the labels for each container, the dataframe needs to be reduced to the corresponding hue value. Pandas' `groupby` can be used to group per hue value.

As the ordering is not necessarily consistent, it helps to force one on the `survey` and `level` columns by making them categorical.

Note that `plt.tight_layout()` should be called after the legend creation, to also fit the legend into the figure.

The following example code assumes seaborn 12.2, which uses `errorbar=None` instead of `ci=None`. A newline character allows the labels to be plotted on two lines. `ax.margins` adds some extra white space to better fit the labels.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

data = { 'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22],
         'survey': ['baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline'],
         'level': ['low', 'high', 'medium', 'low', 'high', 'medium', 'medium', 'high', 'low', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'low', 'medium', 'low', 'high', 'low', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'high', 'high', 'high', 'medium', 'low', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'medium', 'low', 'high', 'high', 'medium', 'medium', 'low', 'high', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# force an order by making the column categorical
df['survey'] = pd.Categorical(df['survey'], ['baseline', 'endline'])
df['level'] = pd.Categorical(df['level'], ['low', 'medium', 'high'])

df_N = df.groupby(['survey', 'level']).count().sort_index(ascending=True).reset_index()
df_N['%'] = 100 * df_N['id'] / df_N.groupby('survey')['id'].transform('sum')

sns.set_style('white')
ax = sns.barplot(data=df_N, x='survey', y='%', errorbar=None,
                 palette="rainbow", hue='level')

for container, (level, df_N_level) in zip(ax.containers, df_N.groupby('level')):
    labels = [f'{pct:.1f}%\n$(N={n})$' for pct, n in zip(df_N_level['%'], df_N_level['id'])]
    ax.bar_label(container, labels, fontsize=10)

sns.despine(ax=ax, left=True)
ax.grid(True, axis='y')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(100))
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_ylabel('')
ax.margins(y=0.15)  # optionally some more free space at the top
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot with hue and bar labels with counts]